# ERROR: Deployment failed. Fetching deployment informat$APPLICATION_NAME

Tags: nodejs-server

Hi I was trying to deploy on windows ec2. But having an error code deploy is deploying on different location, maybe problem is with my appspec.yml file. It is my first deployment on windows ec2 using bitbucket pipeline. Please shame me how I can set appspec.yml file. Thank you!!!

Comment: provide more information such as: the type of nodejs-server you are deploying, do you deploy manually or using ci/cd script? what does that script looks like?

Comment: I am using bitbucket pipeline. Script is too long